# write a string behind a specific string into a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I need some help with a bash function. Although I already asked a similar question I'm still to silly to write this on my own.

**My problem**

I'd like to write a domain or subdomain given by the user trough read -p to the /etc/hosts file.

The domain should be added behind a specific ip in the file. The IP is stored in the variavle $secondadapter, The $secondadapter var is stored as global variable in  /etc/profile.d/file.sh so every user have access to it.

I'm not familiar with grep and sed or awk so my function fails. Here is what I have written

```
writetohostsfile(){
hosts_file=/etc/hosts
if ! grep -q '$domain' "${hosts_file}" ; then
grep -F '${secondadapter}' "${hosts_file}" | echo -n " $domain"
else
echo "This domain already exists!"
fi  
}
```

Any help and any links with good post to learn about grep and sed are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated. This should be bold enough to make it work.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter domain name: " domain

# . <(exec grep ^secondadapter= /etc/profile.d/file.sh)  ## Uncomment if the variable was not yet exported.

if [[ $secondadapter =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    if grep "^$secondadapter[[:space:]]\+[^#]\+" /etc/hosts >/dev/null; then
        exp="s/^\(${secondadapter//./\\.}[[:space:]]\+[^#]\+\)/\1 $domain/"
        sed -i "$exp" /etc/hosts
    else
        echo "$secondadapter $domain" >> /etc/hosts
    fi
else
    echo "Value of \$secondadapter is invalid: $secondadapter"
fi
```

Comment: That's not correct syntax for /etc/hosts. The IP goes first. And you can't duplicate IPs in the file -- he's adding an alias to an existing line.

Comment: @user121261 It runs exactly like that but I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. Are you using a GNU version of grep and sed?

Comment: I found the solution this has had nothing to do with you function. It works perfect. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This will add the domain to the matching line of `/etc/hosts`:

```
sed -i.bak "/^$secondadapter[ \t]/s/$/ $domain/" /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Let's assume I run the script twice Will the .back file be overwritten or will this create an aditional file every time I execute the script?

Comment: It will be overwritten. If you want to keep more history, you'll have to do that yourself.